# MongoDB move array element

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

Suppose I have a collection in MongoDB with the following schema:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID,
    "Entries": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectID,
            "Content": string
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to edit the "Content" field of an element from the array "Entries" and then move that element to the first index - zero - so that the array is sorted descending by when the elements were last changed. Can this be accomplished in an 'atomic' query that I can put in one db.collection.update?

If not, should I use say a UNIX timestamp and then just sort by that when querying? Is the performance difference noticable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using objectId inside your array, then part of this id is a timestamp.

That means you can always determine when field was created. If you need to deal with last update - then timestamp field will solve this problem, as I personally will not relay on array position.

See more about objectID and python [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html)